# How to return a 410 status code in Next.js within getStaticProps and getStaticPath?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm working on a Next.js project and I need to return a 410 status code (Gone) for a specific page. I want to indicate to search engines and clients that the page no longer exists.

```
export async function getStaticProps({ params: { name } }) {
  const user = await fetchUser(name)
  if (!user) {
    return {
      notFound: true, //404 but I want 410
    };
  }
  return {
    props: {
      user
    }, // will be passed to the page component as props
    revalidate: 60, // In seconds
  };
}
```

I've searched for a solution but haven't found a clear answer.
this is extracted from documentation:

```
import Error from 'next/error'
 
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const res = await fetch('https://api.github.com/repos/vercel/next.js')
  const errorCode = res.ok ? false : res.status
  const json = await res.json()
 
  return {
    props: { errorCode, stars: json.stargazers_count },
  }
}
 
export default function Page({ errorCode, stars }) {
  if (errorCode) {
    return <Error statusCode={errorCode} />
  }
 
  return <div>Next stars: {stars}</div>
}
```

but this is the client-side UI for the error, not the server-side status code for crawlers.

The server-side solution that worked is:

```
export async function getServerSideProps({ params: { name } }) {
  const user = await fetchUser(name)
  if (!user) {
    res.statusCode = 410;
    return {
      user: null,
    };
  }
  return {
    props: {
      user
    }, // will be passed to the page component as props
    revalidate: 60, // In seconds
  };
}
```

Now the problem is I lost the ISR feature and switched to the getServerSideProps approach

Could someone please explain how I can return a 410 status code in Next.js within getStaticProps and getStaticPath?

Comment: Try using https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/custom-error#more-advanced-error-page-customizing but put `return { statusCode: 410 }` instead?

Comment: @evolutionxbox No, because these are only ui, not the SSR Status Code.

Comment: @AhmedI.Elsayed please at least read the question with detail carefully before downvoting.

Comment: @KomeilMehranfar consider using [`getServerSideProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/rendering/server-side-rendering) in conjunction with my previous comment?

Comment: it worked by adding res.statusCode = 410; before return. but actually, it changed my logic a little bit because I lost the ISR features and performance because of changing getStaticProps to getServerSideProps.

Comment: AFAIK client side code cannot return http error codes?

Comment: No, it can not. status code is the server response.